# Representing the maze in the Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, solver, maze

I am a new computer science student, and now we know the Python language. It is beautiful, but I have many problems with it. Sorry, I can solve this question.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGRQD.png)

I tried to solve it using the Dictionary, but I did not know how to represent it well. I only know how to represent simple things.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're thinking about how to represent a problem in the form of a data structure, you should usually start by thinking about what you will need to do with the structure -- what questions do you want it to be able to answer?  For the case of a maze, I'd probably start with "given a cell in the maze, I want to know what other cells I can get to".

With a dictionary, you could make each cell a key, with the values being a list of the other reachable cells.  Hence:

```
maze = {
    'A1': ['A2'],
    'A2': ['A1', 'B2'],
    ...
}
```

Given that structure it'd be pretty easy to write a BFS that would tell you the shortest path between any two cells.

Comment: Sorry, can you complete the solution to understand the question will?,  because of the partitions. I do not know how to act, and I knew these two steps beforehand. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: If you're hoping for someone to do the assignment for you to turn in without having to understand it, there are paid services for that.  If you're trying to understand how to represent the maze as a dictionary, I think this answer will help you, but you may need to take a little more time to understand it -- your comment about partitions makes me think that you may have skimmed over it quickly, since that is definitely addressed in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I understood it and solved it. There was a problem I had, which was that I did not know how many moves C2 should make. But I asked the teacher today and I understood the solution. She wanted the graph to be direct, meaning it did not go backward. Thank you very much for helping me.